# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll returned by WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have and MVC project using WebApi.  I am trying to call an update stored procedure in my database. The update works by on my webapiresponse, my project halts and I receive the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".  For the life of me I can't figure out what it is saying is null.

Here is my method in my MVC Controller:

```
        public void UpdateNCMSID(string ncmsId)
    {
        contractorId = UserInfo.targetCompanyID;
        CommonClient.UpdateNCMSID(contractorId, ncmsId);
    }
```

Here is the WebApi Client method:

```
public static HttpContent ConstructNCMSContent(int CompanyID, string vchNCMSIDNumber)
    {
        return new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CompanyID", CompanyID.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("vchNCMSIDNumber", vchNCMSIDNumber.ToString())

        });
    }
    public Task<int> UpdateNCMSID(int CompanyID, string vchNCMSIDNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var content = ConstructNCMSContent(CompanyID, vchNCMSIDNumber);
            var uri = new Uri("api/UpdateNCMSID/", UriKind.Relative);
            var response = PerformPost<int>(uri, content, true);
            return response;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here is the method in the WebApi Service:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/UpdateNCMSID")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateNCMSID(ParametersNCMSModel pm)
    {

        var result = _db.sxUpdateNCMSIDNumberByCompanyID(pm.CompanyID, pm.vchNCMSIDNumber);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Both parameters have value the error occurs in the code below:

```
        protected async Task<T> PerformPost<T>(Uri uri, HttpContent content, bool IsAuthenticated)
    {
        _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress }; 
       if (IsAuthenticated) AppendDefaultHeaders(_webApiClient);
       var webApiResponse = await _webApiClient.PostAsync(uri,content);
       var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
```

The error happens on this line:

```
var webApiResponse = await _webApiClient.PostAsync(uri,content);
```

After the program halts and I restart, I can see that the update did indeed happen in the database.  Will someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the exception being thrown inside of your try/catch? Try running the app in a debugger and find out exactly what is null.

Comment: No.  It is being thrown in PerformPost<T> at the line webApiResponse